# Can't click users tab in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I finally managed to install mysql-server-5.7 and phpmyadmin. I got root permissions, can log in with it everywhere, etc. What I can't do is to get to the Users tab in phpmyadmin web panel. Clicking there does nothing, or maybe just refreshes page because warning from main page (different versions of php installed) disappears.

How to regain access to this panel?

Comment: Can you run `select * from mysql.user`?

Comment: I may be paranoid but I suspect that getting a warning on home page means the application is not correctly installed.

Comment: try logging in from the terminal with mysql -u root -p

Comment: `Your PHP MySQL library version 5.5.49 differs from your MySQL server version 5.7.12. This may cause unpredictable behavior.`
this is warning, yes I can select users from mysql both via terminal and using phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Mike have you managed to fix the problem? I am having the same issue, but I don't have that warning about different MySQL versions

Comment: Yes I did. I uninstalled and purged everything, deleted all remnants, etc. and then installed MariaDB and phpmyadmin. That helped and fixed the problem. I didn't post it here because it's just bypassing the problem.